# Can't get MySQL to accept NOT EXISTS before INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, exists

Please note that I can't solve this by putting a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table. This is business logic: If the value to be placed in a certain column is N, we allow duplicate rows.  For any other value, we don't.

So after checking the value of the incoming parameter and finding that it's not the one we allow dupes of, I do this:

```
INSERT INTO userItems
VALUES ('0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A', '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c', 'like', NULL)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM userItems WHERE userID = '0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A' AND itemID = '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c' AND action = 'like')
```

This results in: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user...`

Using `IF NOT EXISTS` doesn't work either.  Tried this too:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM userItems WHERE userID = '0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A' AND itemID = '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c' AND action = 'like')
THEN
INSERT INTO userItems VALUES ('0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A', '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c', 'like', NULL)  
END IF
```

Using `SELECT` (as suggested) to provide the values instead of `VALUES` doesn't insert anything, even in a stand-alone statement.  This:

```
INSERT INTO userItems (SELECT '541C3FFB-0711-4949-AD23-538B19F598D6', '10sz61gbuo2k11938s', 'like', NULL FROM userItems)
```

Doesn't do anything (no rows inserted, even when table is totally empty).

But a `VALUES` one does:

```
INSERT INTO userItems VALUES ('541C3FFB-0711-4949-AD23-538B19F598D6', '10sz61gbuo2k11938s', 'like', NULL)
```

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` should be part of a select statement, it doesnt work with `VALUES`.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT  userItems 
(SELECT  
   '0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A',
   '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c',
   'like',
    NULL
 FROM 
    userItems
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM userItems 
     WHERE userID = '0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A' AND 
           itemID = '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c' AND 
           action = 'like'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but no dice.  That's what I originally tried, but it throws a syntax error also: "...the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS 
(  SELECT * FROM user..."

Comment: Thanks, but still nope: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM userItems 
        WHERE user..."

Comment: Thanks, that finally works.  But what a syntactically asinine workaround.  I wonder why nobody can explain the failure of the IF NOT EXISTS construction.

Comment: WOOPS: Doesn't work after all. The insert doesn't do anything.  In fact, even that insert statement by itself doesn't do anything.  I'll update my question with details.

Comment: @Oscar : So, have you succeeded using `VALUES`?

Comment: No, because so far I can't find any way to implement the "if" logic (aside from a stored procedure).  For now, I have my PHP doing a query for an identical record and only doing the insert if it doesn't get one.

Answer (score 1):

Since normal table constraints won't work because of the "mostly unique" rule, `INSERT` doesn't take a `WHERE` clause, and bare flow control is bad syntax, I'd wrap the logic in a procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createUserItem;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createUserItem (
    IN pUserID VARCHAR(35), 
    IN pItemID VARCHAR(35), 
    IN pAction VARCHAR(8), 
    IN pCol4   VARCHAR(4)
) 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 'X'
          FROM userItems 
         WHERE userID = pUserID 
           AND itemID = pItemID 
           AND action = pAction
    ) THEN
        INSERT INTO userItems ()
        VALUES (pUserID, pItemID, pAction, pCol4);
   END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you use `CALL`

```
mysql> CALL createUserItem('0AA4DC20-5038-4A24-100F4DB16C6A', '1qubydk59mo059x4w2q99c', 'like', NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for that input.  Just curious: I assume that you're referring to the second example as "bare flow control"; why is it bad syntax?  And also: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It's bad syntax in the sense that it returns a syntax error. That's because [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) can only be used inside a stored procedure or function context.